# Need T-SQL pivot with dynamic date range counting occurrence

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I need help on a pivot in T-SQL which I can't make work.

These are the requirements:

1. Need to define a Startdate and EndDate as "yyyy-MM"
2. Aggregate on Month level
3. Each month only one "ClientID" must be counted (see "A" in 2018-05)

I have this table with sample data:

```
ClientID    Model   LastSyncTime_DW
---------------------------------------------
1           A       2018-09-26 00:00:00.000
2           A       2018-09-05 00:00:00.000
1           A       2018-08-19 00:00:00.000
1           A       2018-07-25 00:00:00.000
3           B       2018-07-03 00:00:00.000
1           A       2018-06-10 00:00:00.000
3           B       2018-06-07 00:00:00.000
8           A       2018-06-01 00:00:00.000
1           A       2018-05-31 00:00:00.000 (duplicate ClientID for this month - count only one)
3           B       2018-05-29 00:00:00.000
4           C       2018-05-26 00:00:00.000
5           D       2018-05-25 00:00:00.000
6           C       2018-05-24 00:00:00.000
1           A       2018-05-19 00:00:00.000 (duplicate ClientID for this month - count only one)
7           D       2018-05-12 00:00:00.000
8           A       2018-05-09 00:00:00.000
9           A       2018-05-05 00:00:00.000
```

The result should be like this:

```
Model   2018-09 2018-08 2018-07 2018-06 2018-5
-----------------------------------------------
A       2       1       1       2       3
B                       1       1       
C                                       2
D                                       2
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select model,
       count(distinct case when LastSyncTime_DW >= '2018-09-01' and LastSyncTime_DW < '2018-10-01' then ClientID end) as cnt_201809,
       count(distinct case when LastSyncTime_DW >= '2018-08-01' and LastSyncTime_DW < '2018-10-01' then ClientID end) as cnt_201808,
       . . .
from t
group by model;
```

The major difference from your results is that this returns `0`s instead of `NULL`s.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. It works so far but I need the startDate and endDate dynamically defined. Need this query to generate reports with SQL Report Server where startDate and endDate are different all the time. So the "count" part must be kind of dynamic. Any idea for this?

Comment: @Fridolin . . . That requires dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Create table #Pivot 
    (ClientID     int,Model  varchar(2),LastSyncTime_DW datetime)

    Insert into #Pivot Values   (1, 'A',    '2018-09-26'),
                        (2, 'A',    '2018-09-05'),
                        (1, 'A',    '2018-08-19'),
                        (1, 'A',    '2018-07-25'),
                        (3, 'B',    '2018-07-03'),
                        (1, 'A',    '2018-06-10'),
                        (3, 'B',    '2018-06-07'),
                        (8, 'A',    '2018-06-01'),
                        (1, 'A',    '2018-05-31'),
                        (3, 'B',    '2018-05-29'),
                        (4, 'C',    '2018-05-26'),
                        (5, 'D',    '2018-05-25'),
                        (6, 'C',    '2018-05-24'),
                        (1, 'A',    '2018-05-19'),
                        (7, 'D',    '2018-05-12'),
                        (8, 'A',    '2018-05-09'),
                        (9, 'A',    '2018-05-05')

Select * from #Pivot

  select model,
   count(distinct case when LastSyncTime_DW >= '2018-09-01' and LastSyncTime_DW < '2018-10-01' then ClientID end) as cnt_201809,
   count(distinct case when LastSyncTime_DW >= '2018-08-01' and LastSyncTime_DW < '2018-09-01' then ClientID end) as cnt_201808,
   count(distinct case when LastSyncTime_DW >= '2018-07-01' and LastSyncTime_DW < '2018-08-01' then ClientID end) as cnt_201807,
   count(distinct case when LastSyncTime_DW >= '2018-06-01' and LastSyncTime_DW < '2018-07-01' then ClientID end) as cnt_201806,
   count(distinct case when LastSyncTime_DW >= '2018-05-01' and LastSyncTime_DW < '2018-06-01' then ClientID end) as cnt_201805
 from #Pivot
 group by model;
```

You will get the Following Results

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. It works so far but I need the startDate and endDate dynamically defined. Need this query to generate reports with SQL Report Server where startDate and endDate are different all the time. So the "count" part must be kind of dynamic. Any idea for this?